# Generating a secondary reference from a userform to be generated in only 1 sheet when data is going to multiple sheets

Tags: database, vba, excel, userform

Hi I was hoping someone could help please.

I currently have a dilemma. I have a code here which works perfectly for simple data entry. Simply pop the information into a userform and then click the button the information gets sent to a mastersheet (ws1), as well as 1 or 2 of the other 3 sheets it may need to depending on specific qualifying aspects.

The issue I have here is the mastersheet has a reference which is simply the next number in a sequence. Should the data entered qualify the for ws2 I am wanting it to then generate another reference number which would again be the next number in a sequence **(within that sheet only)**.

Below is my code which is generating the number but it will bring the number that should only be shown on ws2 across all sheets the data will be present on. is anyone able to assist?

Thanks,

```
Function GetNextId(ws As Worksheet, col As Variant) As Long
    GetNextId = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Columns(col)) + 1
End Function

Private Sub DataEntry ()
Dim mRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Nextnum As Long
Dim Xnum As Long



Set ws1 = Worksheets("MasterData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("X")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("A")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("C")

Nextnum = GetNextId(Sheets("MasterData"), "A")
Xnum = GetNextId(Sheets("X"), "AC")

Dim TargetWorksheets As Variant
'16 qualifying scenarios to determine where the data will be sent

Select Case True
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtClaimVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws4)
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
Case ComboPD.Value = "N" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value < 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)

Case Else: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1)
End Select

For Each ws In TargetWorksheets

'find first empty row in worksheets
mRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'copy userform info data to the qualifying database sheets
ws.Cells(mRow, 1).Value = Nextnum
ws.Cells(mRow, 2).Value = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
ws.Cells(mRow, 3).Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM:SS")
ws.Cells(mRow, 4).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "WW"))
ws.Cells(mRow, 5).Value = Format(Date, "MMM-YY")
ws.Cells(mRow, 6).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "YYYY"))
ws.Cells(mRow, 7).Value = 1
ws.Cells(mRow, 8).Value = TxtWt.Value * (1300 / 1000)
ws.Cells(mRow, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBd.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("G:H"), 2, False)
ws.Cells(mRow, 10).Value = Application.UserName
                If ComboBd.Value = "Mn" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCompany.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("L:N"), 2, False) Else
                   If ComboBd.Value = "Pur" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCompany.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False) Else
                       If ComboBd.Value = "Vog" Then ws.Cells(mRow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False)
ws.Cells(mRow, 12).Value = Format(Me.TxtRD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
ws.Cells(mRow, 13).Value = ComboPD.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 14).Value = ComboNP.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 15).Value = ComboBd.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 16).Value = ComboCom.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 17).Value = TxtAdditional.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 18).Value = Format(Me.TxtDD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
ws.Cells(mRow, 19).Value = TxtBn.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 20).Value = TxtFS.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 21).Value = ComboPr.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 22).Value = ComboIs.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 23).Value = TxtUn.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 24).Value = TxtWt.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 25).Value = TxtIn.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 26).Value = TxtDt.Value
ws.Cells(mRow, 27).Value = TxtShp.Value
ws.cells(mRow, 29).Value = Xnum

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a second Select Case at the end

```
    ws.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = DateValue(Me.TxtRecDate.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDOD.Value)

Select Case True

        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 1: ws.Cells(mRow, 29).Value = Xnum
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "Y" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 1: ws.Cells(mRow, 29).Value = Xnum
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) <= 3: ws.Cells(mRow, 29).Value = Xnum
        Case ComboPD.Value = "Y" And ComboNP.Value = "N" And txtCVal.Value >= 50 And DateValue(Me.TxtRD.Value) - DateValue(Me.TxtDD.Value) > 3: ws.Cells(mRow, 29).Value = Xnum

End Select
```